# SetError with setFocusable(false) in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having an edittext and an icon. Clicking on this icon I show DateTime Picker. I have set `setFocusable(false);` and using setError on this edittext. But when any error occurs only icon is getting shown. Text is not getting shown at all. I have tried `_input.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` also but it gives users to enter any text in this edittext which I do not want as I have created this edittext for date time only.

So, how can I show the error message then, can someone please help me.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use an edittext, if you do not want the user to input text? you can use a `textView` and `textView.setText("your time")` instead.

Comment: When I am using textview.setError it is giving me the icon of the error on the textview but it is not giving me the text of the error.

Comment: I resolved this issue by setting `testview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        textview.setFocusable(true);` in my code and `textview.requestFocus()` when I setError on this testview.

Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Add following lines to your code:

```
et.setFocusable(true);
et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
et.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use like this if you want to set Error on your edittext with icon

> ed_emailId.setError("your Error message",R.drawable.ic_profile);

and if you want to set only error and icon will default then use like

> ed_emailId.setError("your Error message");

i hope this will help you